# Handling Missing Web Elements-Page Object Model

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests

I Use Page Object Model in my framework. I have defined all webelements to be returned via static methods. eg:

```
public class Login_Page {

private static WebElement element = null;

public static WebElement Textbox_UserName (WebDriver driver)
{

    element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='username']"));

    return element;

}
```

And In my Test I use this to enter user name by:

```
     @Test (priority=1)
  public static void Verify_Login() 
// Verify Logging in with right credentials
   {    
      driver.get("myurl");
      Login_Page.Textbox_UserName(driver).sendKeys
       }
```

The challenge that I face is: 
Suppose this element does not exist in the application, say the xpath has changed, I get a  "NO such element Exception" at Login_Page class when the Textbox_UserName method is executed.
Hence the script does not even come to my test Case Verify_login()method where I actually enter the Failure into my report.

```
 if (Login_Page.TextBox_UserName(driver).isVisible()==true)
      {
          //PASS
      }else
      {
          //FAIL
              }
```

Can anyone please suggest how I can catch that "No Such element exception" from there and use it in my report which is executed from my if/else condition ?? 
I tried using Try/Catch block and returned exception , but since the return type is webElement in the TextBox_Username () static method, I am not able to do it. 
Any help is appreciated. thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

I use page object model all the time but I do it differently because of the issue that you are running into (and issues like it). I only grab the element when I need it. So rather than grabbing all the elements on the page, e.g. `PageFactory` and the like, I wait until I'm about to click an element before I scrape the element.

Below is an example page object that shows what I'm talking about.

If an element doesn't exist, you will get the error when you try to click it. You will see that the element doesn't exist from the exception message, you can investigate the page and determine what the locator needs to be changed, you go to the top of the page and change the locator, rebuild, and run the test. Problem solved. :)

```
package sandbox;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class PageObject
{
    private WebDriver driver;
    private By waitForLocator = By.id("someId"); // this is a locator for some element on the page that is last to load

    private By buttonLocator = By.id("sampleId");
    private By usernameLocator = By.id("usernameId");
    private By productNameLocator = By.id("productId");

    public PageObject(WebDriver webDriver)
    {
        this.driver = webDriver;

        // wait for page to finish loading
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(waitForLocator));

        // see if we're on the right page
        if (!driver.getCurrentUrl().contains("samplePage.jsp"))
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException("This is not the XXXX Sample page. Current URL: " + driver.getCurrentUrl());
        }
    }

    public void clickButton()
    {
        driver.findElement(buttonLocator).click();
    }

    public String getProductName()
    {
        return driver.findElement(productNameLocator).getText();
    }

    public void setUsername(String username)
    {
        driver.findElement(usernameLocator).sendKeys(username);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Try-Catch block in your code for `Verify_Login` method

```
 @Test (priority=1)
 public static void Verify_Login() {
// Verify Logging in with right credentials
   try{
        //YOUR CODE
    }
   catch(NoSuchElementException nsee) {
        System.out.println("You are getting No Such Element Exception");          
        //Perform What you want if exception happens
    }
   catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("You are getting other Exception");          
        //Perform What you want if any other exception happens (Except NoSuchElementException )
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ashish-This did not work. The NOSuchElement exception is not coming from the Verify_Login method. it comes from the static method in the PAge class. SO this method wont work :(

Answer (score 0):

If you're using try catch, you can return null to your method like this:

```
public static WebElement Textbox_UserName (WebDriver driver){   
        WebElement element = null;
        try {
            element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='username']"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return element;
}
```

Then

```
 if (Login_Page.TextBox_UserName(driver)!=null){
      //PASS
 }else{
      //FAIL
 }
```

You should use `WebDriverWait` to avoid catching errors while the browser is loading.

```
public static WebElement Textbox_UserName (WebDriver driver){   
     WebDriverWait wait = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);           
     WebElement element = null;

     try {
         wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//div[@class='username']"));
         element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='username']"));
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return element;
}
```

Comment: @SDBot- Thanks, but the issue is not the No Such elementException. I am not able get that error and use it in my If/else block of Verify_login.

Comment: I create the NoSuchElementException so that I get an error. I willfully changed the xpath so that I get that exception. So it was not a wait issue. I wanted to get that error which is thrown as type exception be captured in my Verify_Login method so that I can log into my reports .